# Jsdoc is not excluding paths

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I'm using Jsdoc 3.6.2. I have this source configuration in conf.json:

```
"source": {
        "exclude":["MyProj/excludeFolder"],
        "includePattern": ".+\\.js(doc|x|xinc)?$",
        "excludePattern": "(^|\\/|\\\\)_"
    }
```

When I execute `jsdoc -r -c pathToMy/conf.json` on MyProj directory , Jsdoc is not excluding 'excludeFolder' folder. I know that it is using the correct config.json file because it's including all .jsxinc files. How can I fix that?

EDIT: 
I'm working on Windows 10 and vscode. Jsdoc is installed globally on C:/Users/myUser/appData/Roaming/npm. I've created a toy project on C:/Users/myUser/myProject with the following structure:

```
myProject/
|-out/
    |-conf.json
|-src/
    |-includeFile.jsxinc
    |-excludeFolder/
        |-exludeFile.jsxinc
```

This is the full conf.json:

```
{
    "tags": {
        "allowUnknownTags": true
    },
    "source": {
        "exclude":["myProject/src/excludeFolder"],
        "includePattern": ".+\\.js(doc|x|xinc)?$",
        "excludePattern": "(^|\\/|\\\\)_"
    },
    "plugins": [],
    "templates": {
        "cleverLinks": false,
        "monospaceLinks": false,
        "default": {
            "outputSourceFiles": true
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code in 'excludeFile.jsxinc':

```
/**
* @class
*/
function excludeClass(){}
```

And this is the code in 'includeFile.jsxinc':

```
/**
* @class
*/
function includeClass(){}
```

When I run the following comand on power shell at C:/Users/myUser/myProject: `jsdoc -c C:/Users/myUser/myProject/out/conf.json -r.`, documentation is generated for both classes: includeClass and excludeClass. In the real project, the exclude folder contains third party libraries that use jsdoc.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue. Can you expand further or create a [mcve]?

Comment: I've edited the cuestion adding more details

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm facing the same issue. It won't exclude `node_modules`.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue and I resolved with this:

```
"excludePattern": "myProject/src/excludeFolder"
```

and delete "exclude" attribute.